# Python stream views

Tags: python

Python has `memoryview` for viewing buffers.

Is there something analogous for io streams, or some library which implements this?

An example of what I'm thinking would be (doesn't work of course):

```
>>> import io
>>> sr = io.BytesIO(b'12345')
>>> print(sr[2:3]).read()
... b'3'
```

(this is just an example, the underlying stream doesn't have to be a buffer at all)

The reason I want views over plain bytes is that the contents underlying the stream may be very large.

Comment: streams already have `.seek` and `.read`; what more do you need?

Comment: What are you trying to do with this library?

Comment: I want to create an independent view of another stream. Of course I could just use seek or read, but it's a convenience, just like memory views.

Answer (score 1):

You may consider [mmap](https://docs.python.org/3/library/mmap.html) module. As far as I understand your needs it may provide required functionality.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried that out and a slice returned type `bytes`. I updated the question to say the purpose of using streams.

Comment: With `mmap` you pass the responsibility of loading appropriate regions (called `pages`) of a file into memory and _unloading_ unused ones to an operating system. If you need a more precise control on how caching should behave in different usage scenarios you should step down to a particular system facilities, e.g. [mmap(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap) for Linux. If you don't need such precision you can safely assume that regions of a file are loaded when you access them and unloaded some time later.